# change this javascript to generate more than one random number

Tags: javascript, jjs

running this code will give me one random number what I need is to change it to generate me 1000 on each run

```
function randomdnumber(){
    var randomdnumber = "";
    var nb = new Array();
    nb[9] = 0;

    for(i = 0,y = 10 ; i < 9 ; i++,y--)
        nb[i] = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)),nb[9] += (nb[i]*y);

    for(i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
        randomdnumber += nb[i];

    nb[9] = nb[9]-(parseInt(nb[9]/11)*11);

    if(nb[9] == 0 || nb[9] == 1)
        randomdnumber += nb[9];
    else
        randomdnumber += (11 - nb[10]);
    return randomdnumber;
}
print(+randomdnumber());
```

Comment: Can't you just put it inside a for loop that goes fom 0 to 999?

Comment: ...why not call the function 1000 times? What Pedro said

Comment: I've tried "for i in {1..1000}; do jjs script.js; done" but it was slow

Answer (score 1):

```
let n = 1000;
Array(n).fill(0).map((e)=>Math.round(Math.random()*(10000000000-100000000) + 100000000))
```

works better